# Передача параметров в контроллер

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

У меня есть `Html.BeginForm`, вот ее код:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.TextBox("searchString", (string)ViewBag.searchString, new { @class = "form-control", name = "searchString", placeholder = "Search..." })    
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />    
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", new { sortOrder = @ViewBag.sortOrder, searchString = ???,  page = 1 }, new { @class = "btn", type = "submit" })    
}
```

По нажатию `<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />` все параметры передаются верно, но мне надо изменить один параметр (`page`) на 1, тк если я буду находится на 4 странице и по клику `button` передадутся все параметры без изменений, то после поиска я буду на пустой 4 странице, а на первой будет результат поиска.

Я попробовал передавать все параметры с помощью `Html.ActionLink`, но не смог найти, как передавать содержимое `Html.TextBox` в качестве параметра.

**Вопросы:**

1. Как правильно изменить параметр `page` по клику `button`?
2. Как передать содержимое `Html.TextBox` в качестве параметра?

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите достичь? Какая-то форма, зачем-то совмещённая с пагинацией и сортировками... Я может что-то не понимаю, но совершенно спокойно убираете Html.ActionLink -- вставляете обычную кнопку `<button>` и все ваши page и sortOrder загоняете в `Html.HiddenFor`. Почитайте тут про [обычную пагинацию](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.13.php), там без форм. Если нужны формы -- то либо дополняйте свой вопрос, либо используйте как я писал HiddenFor + обычный button.

Comment: @AK на странице есть пагинация, сортировки и поиск. Я делаю так, чтоб при переходе на другую страницу, либо при изменении сортировки передавались все данные, а именно `строка поиска` и `вариант сортировки`. Сделал я это при помощи ViewBag. Проблема в том, что когда я нахожусь, например, на 4 странице и нажимаю на `<button>` для поиска, в контроллер со всеми параметрами передается страница, а при поиске страницу передавать не надо, либо ей надо задать значение `1`. Вот я и не могу понять, как это сделать..

Comment: Ну так и уберите из формы page, раз оно у вас ненужно и вообще константное. А в контроллере поставьте значение по дефолту int page = 1 И ещё уберите Actionlink вообще, замените на button, а в sortOrder пусть формируется из TextBox PS Привели бы код контроллера и полностью код view -- не пришлось бы на пальцах вам мне объяснять, а мне -- вам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так мне удалось решить свою проблему:

```
<input type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewBag.SearchString" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="page" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />
```